# How to predict the outcome of a regression holding regressor constant?

Tags: r, workflow, non-linear-regression, piecewise

Hi everyone based on the wage-dataset (wage being the dependent variable) and on the workflow created below, I would like to find out the following:

1. What is the predicted `wage` of a person with `age` equal to 30 for each piecewise model?
2. Considering the flexible `pw6_wf_fit` model configuration and in particular the six breakpoints above: Exceeding which (approximate) value of `age` correlates strongest with `wage`?

I tried to use versions of `extract` but so far I don´t know how to apply it in R. Helpful for any comment

The code I use is the following:

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
# load (or install if pacman cannot find an existing installation) the relevant packages
pacman::p_load(
  tidyverse, tidymodels, ISLR, patchwork,
  rpart, rpart.plot, randomForest, gbm, kernlab, parsnip, skimr
)
```

```
data(Wage, package = "ISLR")

Wage %>% 
  tibble::as_tibble() %>% 
  skimr::skim()
```

```
lin_rec   <- recipe(wage ~ age, data = Wage)
# Specify as linear regression
lm_spec <- 
  linear_reg() %>%
  set_mode("regression") %>%
  set_engine("lm")
```

```
plot_model <- function(wf_fit, data) {
  
  predictions <- 
    tibble::tibble(age = seq(min(data$age), max(data$age))) %>% 
    dplyr::bind_cols(
      predict(wf_fit, new_data = .),
      predict(wf_fit, new_data = ., type = "conf_int")
    )
    
  p <- ggplot2::ggplot(aes(age, wage), data = data) +
    geom_point(alpha = 0.05) +
    geom_line(aes(y = .pred),
              data = predictions, color = "darkgreen") +
    geom_line(aes(y = .pred_lower),
              data = predictions, linetype = "dashed", color = "blue") +
    geom_line(aes(y = .pred_upper),
              data = predictions, linetype = "dashed", color = "blue") +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(20, 80, 5)) +
    labs(title = substitute(wf_fit)) +
    theme_classic()
  
  return(p)
  
}
```

```
pw3_rec <- lin_rec %>% step_discretize(age, num_breaks = 3, min_unique = 5) 
pw4_rec <- lin_rec %>% step_discretize(age, num_breaks = 4, min_unique = 5) 
pw5_rec <- lin_rec %>% step_discretize(age, num_breaks = 5, min_unique = 5) 
pw6_rec <- lin_rec %>% step_discretize(age, num_breaks = 6, min_unique = 5)
```

```
pw3_wf_fit <- workflow(pw3_rec, lm_spec) %>% fit(data = Wage)
pw4_wf_fit <- workflow(pw4_rec, lm_spec) %>% fit(data = Wage)
pw5_wf_fit <- workflow(pw5_rec, lm_spec) %>% fit(data = Wage)
pw6_wf_fit <- workflow(pw6_rec, lm_spec) %>% fit(data = Wage)
```

```
(plot_model(pw3_wf_fit, Wage) + plot_model(pw4_wf_fit, Wage)) /
(plot_model(pw5_wf_fit, Wage) + plot_model(pw6_wf_fit, Wage))
```

Comment: I left an answer to the first question, but I'm not entirely sure what you want in the second question.  You want to calculate the correlation between wage and age for values of age greater than some chosen value (say `a`).  Then you want to know which value of `a` maximizes the correlation?  Since the piecewise functions are flat, I suspect it will be values of age close to the beginning of the distribution.  Those values near the end of the distribution will be correlated with wage at 0 because there is no variance in the predictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the first question is pretty straightforward:

```
map(list(pw3_wf_fit, pw4_wf_fit, pw5_wf_fit, pw6_wf_fit), 
    ~predict(.x, new_data=tibble(age=30))) %>% 
  bind_rows()

# # A tibble: 4 × 1
#   .pred
#   <dbl>
# 1  99.3
# 2  94.2
# 3  92.3
# 4  89.5
```